# Java's String Garbage Collection: Or Why Is This Consuming So Much Memory

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

**Solved**

I'm trying to understand why one of my unit tests is consuming so much memory. The first thing I did was run just that one test and measure with VisualVM:

[image]

The initial flat line is due to a `Thread.sleep()` at the start of the test to give VisualVM time to start up.

The test (and setup method) are quite simple:

```
@BeforeClass
private void setup() throws Exception {
    mockedDatawireConfig = mock(DatawireConfig.class);
    when(mockedDatawireConfig.getUrl()).thenReturn(new URL("http://example.domain.fake/"));
    when(mockedDatawireConfig.getTid()).thenReturn("0000000");
    when(mockedDatawireConfig.getMid()).thenReturn("0000000");
    when(mockedDatawireConfig.getDid()).thenReturn("0000000");
    when(mockedDatawireConfig.getAppName()).thenReturn("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    when(mockedDatawireConfig.getNodeId()).thenReturn("t");

    mockedVersionConfig = mock(VersionConfig.class);
    when(mockedVersionConfig.getDatawireVersion()).thenReturn("000031");

    defaultCRM = new ClientRefManager();
    defaultCRM.setVersionConfig(mockedVersionConfig);
    defaultCRM.setDatawireConfig(mockedDatawireConfig);
}

@Test
public void transactionCounterTest() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(15000L);
    String appInstanceID = "";
    for (Long i = 0L; i < 100000L; i++) {
        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
            Assert.assertNotEquals(defaultCRM.getAppInstanceID(), appInstanceID);
            appInstanceID = defaultCRM.getAppInstanceID();
        }
        ReqClientID r = defaultCRM.getReqClientID(); // This call is where memory use explodes.
        Assert.assertEquals(getNum(r.getClientRef()), new Long(i % 1000));
        Assert.assertEquals(r.getClientRef().length(), 14);
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000L);
}
```

The test is pretty simple: iterate 100K times to ensure that `defaultCRM.getReqClientID()` is generating a proper ReqClientID object with a valid counter between 000-999 and that a randomization prefix properly changes at rollover.

`defaultCRM.getReqClientID()` is where the memory problems occur. Let's take a look:

```
public ReqClientID getReqClientID() {
    ReqClientID req = new ReqClientID();
    req.setDID(datawireConfig.getDid()); // #1
    req.setApp(String.format("%s&%s", datawireConfig.getAppName(), versionConfig.toString())); // #2
    req.setAuth(String.format("%s|%s", datawireConfig.getMid(), datawireConfig.getTid())); // #3

    Long c = counter.getAndIncrement();
    String appID = appInstanceID;
    if(c >= 999L) {
        LOGGER.warn("Counter exceeds 3-digits. Resetting appInstanceID and counter.");
        resetAppInstanceID();
        counter.set(0L);
    }
    req.setClientRef(String.format("%s%s%03dV%s", datawireConfig.getNodeId(), appID, c, versionConfig.getDatawireVersion())); // #4
    return req;
}
```

Pretty simple: Create an object, call some `String` setters, calculate a incrementing counter, and random prefix on rollover.

Let's say I comment out the setters (ans associated assertions so they don't fail) numbered #1-#4 above. Memory use is now reasonable:

[image]

Originally I was using simple string concatenation using `+` in the setter components. I changed to `String.format()`, but that hasn't had any effect. I've also tried `StringBuilder` with `append()` to no effect.

I've also tried a few GC settings. In particular, I tried `-XX:+UseG1GC`, `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35`, and `-Xms1g -Xmx1g` (note that 1g is still unreasonable on my buildslave, and I'd like to get it down around max 256m). Here's the graph:

[image]

Going down to `-Xms25m -Xmx256m` causes OutOfMemoryError.

I'm confused by this behavior for third reasons. First, I don't understand the extreme growth in **unused** heap space in the first graph. I create an object, create some strings, pass the strings to the object, and delete the object by letting it go out of scope. Obviously, I don't expect perfect reuse of memory, but why is the JVM seemingly allocating more heap space for these objects every time? The way that unused heap space grows so substantially faster seems really, really wrong. Especially with the more aggressive GC settings, I'd expect to see the JVM attempt to reclaim these totally unreferenced objects before plowing through gigs of memory.

Second, in graph #2, it's apparent that the actual problem are the strings. I've tried to do some reading on ways to compose strings, literals/interned, etc., but I can't see many alternatives beyond `+`/`String.format()`/`StringBuilder`, which all seem to produce the same results. Am I missing some magical way to build strings?

Lastly, I know 100K iterations is overboard, and I could test the rollover with, say, 2K, but I'm trying to understand what's happening in the JVM.

System: OpenJDK x86_64 1.8.0_92 and also Hotspot x86_64 1.8.0_74.

**Edit:**

A couple of people recommended manually invoking `System.gc()` within the test, so I tried doing that every 1K loops. This has an appreciable impact on memory use and a woeful impact on performance:

[image]

The first thing to note is that while used heap space growth is slower, it's still **unbounded**. The only time it totally levels off is once the loop is finished, and the ending `Thread.sleep()` is invoked. A couple of questions:

1) Why is unused heap space still so high? During the very first loop iteration, `System.gc()` is invoked (`i % 1000 == 0`). That actually led to a drop in unused heap space. Why doesn't total heap space ever decrease after the first invocation?

2) Very roughly, every loop iteration 5 allocations are performed: inst ClientReqId and 4 strings. All references to all 5 objects are forgotten on each loop iteration. Total objects essentially remain static (varying only ~±5 objects) throughout the **entire** test. I still don't understand why `System.gc()` isn't more effective at holding used heap space constant when the number of live objects remains constant.

**Edit 2: Solved**

@Jonathan pointed me in the right direction by asking about `mockedDatawireConfig`. This is actually a Spring @ConfigurationProperties class (i.e. Spring loads data from a yaml into an instance and wires the instance where it's needed). In the unit test, I'm not employing anything related to Spring (unit test, not integration test). In this case, it's simply a POJO with getters and setters, but there's not logic in the class.

Anyways, the unit test was using a mocked version of this, which you can see in `setup()` above. I decided to switch to a real instance of the object instead of a mock. That completely solved the issue! It seems to be some issue with Mockito maybe inherent or perhaps since I appear to be using 2.0.2-**beta**. I'll investigate that further and contact the Mockito developers if it does appear to be an unknown issue.

Look at dat sweet, sweet graph:

[image]

Comment: My first guess would be that you create a req object for every iteration instead of reusing it or getting it from a pool. Then next the iterations are too fast for the garbagecollect to clean up unused objects. Have you tried adding garbagecollect() in your function?

Comment: The intention is to create a new object each time. That's the purpose of the unit test. I did try `System.gc()` (tried on each loop and each 1K loops), but it didn't have much effect. The question is why the `ClientReqID r` and its strings aren't being freed after each loop.

Comment: Can you run the test, not use the setters but still do the String.format()? Just to rule out, it has something to do with the String-Pool, which can really have some obscure effects.
Apart from that, can you pinpoint your problem to any specific line 1-4?

Comment: Just one remark on functional correctness: Your cycle-logic in getRequestID is not thread-safe. I assume, that this is an issue, as you use atomic-somethings. Within the `if(c>=999)` the `counter.set(0L)` might raise an multi-using issue if two threads access that code at the same time. Better would be to use `counter.compareAndSet(c, 0L)`

Comment: @Jonathan, Excellent idea on `String.format()`. The graph looks exactly the same as #1, so no improvement. Thanks for the note on the Atomic; I'll be sure to correct it.

Comment: @fandingo Can you test your code with differen JDK versions? If your are experiencing String issues, I would expect in JDK6 that your memory graph for heap memory looks fine, but permgen goes through the roof (String-pooling in JDK up to 6 was in permgen and went elsewhere in Java8).
Which of the 4 lines in question triggers the raise? Any (but slower) or all? Maybe datawire.Config.getDid() does something nasty?

Comment: Regarding your edit: What is rather interesting, is that the growths-ratio is declining. Yes, every iteration is using up more memory but then, the difference is a little less for every iteration. Noticed that?

Comment: Regarding your second-edit-question: Heap is composed of eden, survivor and tenured spaces. Forcing the gc instantly puts all your objects to tenured. As there is a fixed ration between eden and tenured, with every allocated byte of tenured there is some (unused) fraction of bytes in eden allocated. I recommend looking at those figures with JConsole (that allows to split heap for different pools) or install the VisualGC plugin in VisualVM (which lets you peek into the different pools.

Comment: @Jonathan, I'll see what I can do with with older JDK versions, but I do use quite a few Java8 features, although not in this code. It'll take a little surgery to remove the incompatible code for testing. I wasn't aware of VisualGC; I'll give that a shot as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan: "Which of the 4 lines in question triggers the raise?" **All them do. It's less that line X adds some fixed amount; instead it's more like if there's 1 active (3 commented out) it causes a big increase, but it could be any of the 4. Uncommenting more of the string lines obviously causes more memory use, but in a diminishing  manner.**

Comment: "Maybe datawire.Config.getDid() does something nasty?" **That's a straight String getter (no logic) in the actual object, but this object is mocked with Mockito. See `setup()` in my original question.** I was actually wondering how Mockito and javac would handle these literals. Would they be in the constant string pool (since they're known at compile time), or perhaps Mockito may be holding on to instances. I'm going to try with a real object instead of a mock...

Comment: @Jonathan: It was Mockito causing the problem! A million thanks for the help. I put some more details in edit 2 if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's up to the JVM's implementation on how it allocates the heap space. It simply sees a huge (and fast!) increase in Memory Consumption and thus allocates enough heap space to not run into an OutOfMemoryException.

You already saw, that you can change this behavior by playing around with your parameters. You also see that once the usage is constant, the Heap doesn't grow any further (It stops at ~3G instead of growing until ~8G).

To actually see what's happening, you shouldn't do some printf debugging (that means commenting something out and seeing what happens), but rather use your IDE or other tools to examine what is using your memory.

Doing so will show you (for example): 120k instances of String consuming 2GiB or 1.5GiB Garbage and 500MiB as Strings.
Then you clearly know if it's just a lazy collection (because a collection has an overhead) or if you have some references still flying around (I'd say no, because the growth stops).

As a dirty workaround you can also add `System.gc()` calls to your loop to enforce a Garbage-Collection to see if it improves heap usage (at the expense of CPU time of course).

Comment: "but rather use your IDE or other tools to examine what is using your memory." Unfortunately, VisualVM attributes the vast majority of allocations to `java.lang.Object[]` and `short[]` -- not useful. I've tried adding `System.gc()`, and it has some effect, but used heap space still grows to an unreasonable amount. There's only 1 `ClientReqID` active at a time, and it has a handful of strings assigned. While used heap may appear to plateau, it's still way, way too high and perplexing increasing given that the number of active objects is **constant** throughout the list.

Comment: One other thing: "the Heap doesn't grow any further (It stops at ~3G instead of growing until ~8G)." The memory use during the 100K loop **does not** plateau. The plateau is a 10s `Thread.sleep()` at the end of the test (so I can take a heap dump and other debugging in VisualVM).